# error: ‘leftHeight’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I have the following function to computer height of a node in a binary tree (and its descendants):

```
void computeHeight(Node *n) {
    // Implement computeHeight() here.
    if (n->left) {
        computeHeight(n->left);
        int leftHeight = n->left->height;
    } else {
        int leftHeight = -1;
    }
    if (n->right) {
        computeHeight(n->right);
        int rightHeight = n->right->height;
    } else {
        int rightHeight = -1;
    }
    n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
}
```

When I run the code I have `error: ‘leftHeight’ was not declared in this scope`, it happens at line `n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;`. The error happens during compilation.
I don't understand why it happens because I defined `leftHeight` above.
Other code:
In `main.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include "main.h"

void computeHeight(Node *n) {}

int main() {
    Node *n = new Node();
    n->left = new Node();
    n->right = new Node();
    n->right->left = new Node();
    n->right->right = new Node();
    n->right->right->right = new Node();
    computeHeight(n);
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    delete n;
    n = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

In `main.h`:

```
class Node {
public:
  int height; // to be set by computeHeight()
  Node *left, *right;
  Node() { height = -1; left = right = nullptr; }
  ~Node() {
    delete left;
    left = nullptr;
    delete right;
    right = nullptr;
  }
};
```

Comment: You have to declare `leftHeight` and `rightHeight` outside of the `if` block, then initialize them inside.

Comment: What's defined in the braces stays in the braces.

Comment: Thank you, I got it

Comment: A couple quick notes about `Node`. It needs to observe [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). In this case I would most likely disable the copy constructor and assignment operator with `= delete` to prevent bugs from accidental copies. Recursive destruction means you have to watch out for the tree's depth. Too long and the program will recurse off the end of Automatic Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that you have defined `leftHeight` inside `if` `else` block and therefore they are not visible outside of those blocks. Similarly the variable `rightHeight` is also visible only inside the blocks in which it was defined.

To **solve** this just define `leftHeight` outside(of those blocks) once and then just **assign** value to them inside `if` and `else` blocks which would look like:

```
void computeHeight(Node *n) {
    int leftHeight = -1;//define and initialize leftHeight
    int rightHeight = -1;//define and initialize rightHeight
    // Implement computeHeight() here.
    if (n->left) {
        computeHeight(n->left);
        leftHeight = n->left->height;//note this is assignment
    } 
    if (n->right) {
        computeHeight(n->right);
        rightHeight = n->right->height;//note this is assignment
    } 
    n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;//this works now
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it! The only remark is that it's better to initialize the height to -1 and remove `else` blocks

Comment: @pascalamin You're welcome .Yes you do it according to your needs. I was just pointing out how to solve the error you mentioned and didn't take a notice that you could do this without using `else`. Can you mark my answer(or any other) as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Comments and Anoop answer your question. You need to read more about scopes in programming. Functions, loops, conditional statements create their own scopes. Variables created inside those scopes are **local** to those scopes.

In C++ you can create your own scope by just putting braces:

```
int main () { 

   int y  = 1;
   {
      int x = 2;
      y = x; // no error
   }
   x = y; // error 
  
}
```

---

A cleaner working version of your code is the following:

```
void computeHeight(Node *n) {
  int leftHeight = -1;
  int rightHeight = -1;
  // Implement computeHeight() here.
  if (n->left) {
    computeHeight(n->left);
    leftHeight = n->left->height;
  } 

  if (n->right) {
    computeHeight(n->right);
    rightHeight = n->right->height;
  }
  n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
}
```